# My Program does not return a value?

Tags: python-3.x

When I return a value, how comes it doesn't output it? It's probably really simple... and by the way i'm still currently learning Python. I'm using Python 3.x.

```
def convert(operation, temp):
    newTemp = 0
    if (operation is 'F' or operation is 'f'):
        newTemp = (9/5) * (temp + 32)
        return newTemp
    if (operation is 'C' or operation is 'c'):
        newTemp = (5/9) * (temp - 32)
        return newTemp

print ("What operation would you like to convert to? ")
op = input("(F)ahrenheit or (C)elsius: ")
print ()
temp = input("What is the temperature : ")
NewTemp = int(temp)
convert(op, NewTemp)
```

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the `print` thing, your formula for Fahrenheit is incorrect: it should be `9/5 * temp + 32` (no parentheses needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never told it to print the result. Try this:

```
print(convert(op, NewTemp))
```

Comment: Thank You! That helped a lot, ill remember that for next time

Answer (score 0):

You need to `print` the  value returned by `convert(op, NewTemp)`:

```
print(convert(op, NewTemp))
```

Comment: Thank you! Im used to other languages where it just prints on its own. Ill have to remember that for next time